# Android - Make a dynamic counter using setText()

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, counter, settext

I am making a statistical counter that counts upto a certain number (say 60) and the user should see each and every number as it increments on the screen.

```
    TextView display1;
    public int stat1 = 60;
    public void doSomething(View v){

    display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stat);

    for(int i=0;i<=stat1;i++){
        String temp = (String.valueOf(i));
        for(long j=0;j<1000000;j++);
        Log.d("PATO","Value - "+i);
        display1.setText(temp);
        display1.invalidate();
   }
}
```

However, this code only displays the final number i.e. 60 on the screen even though I can see the increments on the debug screen.

Comment: your TextView text is changing from 0 to 60, but you will be able to see only the last index (60). if you want the user to be able to see it, create a timer/interval and add a delay, every time when triggers this internal, you increment your index and update the TextView until index be equals 60.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below solution

```
protected static void startTimer() {
    isTimerRunning = true; 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            elapsedTime += 1; //increase every sec
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

        }
    }, 0, 1000);
};

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        StopWatch.time.setText(formatIntoHHMMSS(elapsedTime)); //this is the textview
    }
}
```

Above code must work...

Note:mHandler must be created in your main thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
As your counter is fast . so display1.setText() is overlapping the value, so you cannot see the previous value, so you can do this :

for(int i=0;i<=stat1;i++){
        String temp = (String.valueOf(i));
Log.d("Value",temp);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        for(long j=0;j<1000000;j++);
        Log.d("PATO","Value - "+i);
        display1.setText(temp);
        display1.invalidate();
   }
}
```